# Override instance behaviour

Tags: haskell, yesod, aeson

Yesod contains `Entity` data type, i.e. model with its id from database. Yesod also makes `Entity` an instance of Aeson's `ToJSON` class, so it could be easily serialized as json. What is more awesome, `Entity` could be wrapped in any structure and it will be serialized as well. There are many types supporting `ToJSON` protocol. It is very handy and I like it a lot.

Unfortunately, serialization format Yesod provides for an `Entity` doesn't fit my needs, I'm looking for an easy and transparent way to change it.

Here is an example. I have simple model

```
data Company = Company
  { companyName :: Text
  }
```

And corresponding Entity would be

```
Entity CompanyId Company
```

Now, code to fetch entities from database and return it as json looks like

```
getCompanyR = do

    -- fetch companies from database
    -- `companies` contains list of `Entity CompanyId Company`
    companies <- runDB $ selectList ([] :: [Filter Company]) []

    -- return it as json
    -- List is also an instance of `ToJSON` so it could be serialized too
    return . toJSON $ companies
```

Serialized list looks like

```
[{"key":"o52553881f14995dade000000","value":{"name":"Pizza World"}}]
```

And I would like it to be

```
[{"id":"o52553881f14995dade000000","name":"Pizza World"}]
```

I can see several options on how to change it each with its drawbacks:

1. Make a function to serialize `Entity` according to my format, but then it will be impossible to serialize `List` of `Entity`ies. I will end writing multiple functions to serialize `Entity` inside any structure it happens to be part of.
2. Make a newtype for an `Entity`, but then I should convert all `Entity`ies to `MyNewEntity`ies prior to serializing. It seems ugly to me, it will result in unnecessary conversion noise.

To summarize, my problem is that I can't change `Entity` `ToJSON` implementation, and I can't make Yesod to return something different than `Entity`. I'm forced to make a conversion, but what is a most transparent way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell's type classes are good when you know, that you'll ever have only one instance. But sometimes you need to serialize the same structure into different representations. That is exactly the issue you have.

I can propose the next solution: Create type class with two parameters (requires `MultiParamTypeClasses` extension). One of them will be the structure you are going to serialize; the second will be a tag to select specific json format. Example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL

-- our custom variant on ToJSON
class ToJSON' tag a where
  toJSON' :: tag -> a -> Value

-- instance for lists, requires FlexibleInstances
instance ToJSON' tag a => ToJSON' tag [a] where
  toJSON' tag l = Array $ Vector.fromList $ map (toJSON' tag) l

-- our data type
data Test = Test {
  testString :: Text,
  testBool :: Bool
  }

-- the tag for the first json format
data TestToJSON1 = TestToJSON1

-- the first json format definition
instance ToJSON' TestToJSON1 Test where
  toJSON' _ test = object [
    "string1" .= String (testString test),
    "bool1" .= Bool (testBool test)
    ]

-- the tag for the second json format
data TestToJSON2 = TestToJSON2

-- the second json format definition
instance ToJSON' TestToJSON2 Test where
  toJSON' _ test = object [
    "string2" .= String (testString test),
    "bool2" .= Bool (testBool test)
    ]

-- usage example
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let test = Test {
    testString = "hello",
    testBool = False
    }
  BSL.putStr $ encode $ toJSON' TestToJSON1 test
  putStrLn ""
  BSL.putStr $ encode $ toJSON' TestToJSON1 [test, test]
  putStrLn ""
  BSL.putStr $ encode $ toJSON' TestToJSON2 test
  putStrLn ""
  BSL.putStr $ encode $ toJSON' TestToJSON2 [test, test]
  putStrLn ""
```

The output:

```
{"string1":"hello","bool1":false}
[{"string1":"hello","bool1":false},{"string1":"hello","bool1":false}]
{"bool2":false,"string2":"hello"}
[{"bool2":false,"string2":"hello"},{"bool2":false,"string2":"hello"}]
```

That way you need to define one `ToJSON'` instance per json format for every data type, and one instance per container (in the example I implemented it only for lists)

If you don't like `MultiParamTypeClasses`, you can pass to `toJSON'` a function that knows how to serialize your data type.

Note: `OverloadedStrings` is not strictly necessary. `FlexibleInstances` is already used inside `Data.Aeson`

Comment: It is definitely a way to go, if you need multiple representations. It's not exactly the issue I have, because I need just one custom representation. I've came up with an easier solution, but yours is more general. Thank you.